Absolute element that are inside container with relative positioning does not move when resizing window
Im new to html/css and from my understanding a absolutely positioned element thats inside of a container with position relative should move with it when resizing window etc, but it does not work at all.
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Medlemsida</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="medlem.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>West Coast Golf</h1>
        </header>
        <img src="./westcoast.png" class="logo" alt="logo"> 
            <section>
                <div class="information"><h2><u>Personlig Information</u></h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Namn: Hasse Eriksson</li>
                        <li>Adress: Smetvägen 4 Lindköping</li>
                        <li>Telefonnummer: 0705243566</li>
                        <li>Betalsätt: Autogiro</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="medlemskap"><h2><u>Medlemskap</u></h2>
                    <img src="./platinum.png" class="platinum" alt="platinum">
                    <button class="button" type="button">Avsluta Medlemskap</button>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
            <div class="handikapp"><h2><u>Handikapp</u></h2>
                <img src="./nineteen.png" class="nineteen" alt="19">
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS
https://jsfiddle.net/g3f5s8zu

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

Try using left in percentage or vw so that it will changes according to screen size but best solution would be using flexbox.

just remove

position:absolute;

and move


     <h1>West Coast Golf</h1>

   
outside of container

OP's question is about the behavior of absolute positioned elements, so simply removing position: absolute; does not answer the question. If you think a different approch to OP's problem is better suited, please explain your reasoning and ideally also share why the snippet in question does not behave as expected.
